# There is a minor alignment issue in the newsletter user details

Tags: bug, design, email, newsletter

There is a minor alignment issue in the Sample Newsletter preview and Newsletter Emails. There is no space between the asked and answered user details.

Screenshot of recent sample newsletter preview:

> [image: In application]

Screenshot of recent newsletter in Email:

> [image: In Email - issue]

On or before June 27, 2019 - there is no alignment issue in the newsletter, screenshot for reference:

> [image: In Email - previous]

Comment: Oh I was about to report the same. This missing space is a bit annoying for the eyes :)